# Search string and add # to the beginning of that line

Tags: text-processing, scripting, cron, vi

Need some help using the `vi` editor.

I am trying to comment out a line on crontab for a specific user.

This is the line on the crontab among many other lines:

`0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 2-23 * * * /home/appuser/CPU_check.sh`

So I want to search the string 'CPU_check' in vi editor (crontab -e) and then add # add the beginning of the line to comment it out.

Lastly, If I need to search in vi editor with two strings e.g. CPU_check and Memory_check and then add # to start of each line containing the strings.

Answer (score 3):

in vi,

```
:g/CPU_check/s/^/#/
```

where

- `:` tell vi to go to command mode
- `g` apply 'globaly' (for multiple line) without g would apply only to first line.
- `/CPU_check/` address line matching `CPU_CHECK`
- `s` substitue
- `/^/` beginning of line (with)
- `/#/` `#` sign

perfom other substitution

save and quit

```
:x
```

Comment: What if I have multiple lines to work with. How can i achieve that?

Comment: insert `g` before pattern match (see edited answer)

Answer (score 0):

You explicitly stated that you wanted a solution using `vi`. But this also can be achieved with a one-liner sed instruction

```
sed -i -e 's/.*CPU_check/# &/' -e 's/.*Memory_check/# &/' crontab
```

This solution changes the file inline. You may wish to save a backup of the  file by changing the `-i` flag to `-i.bak` in the sed invocation.

Comment: I'll try the solution out. Also a quick note. I don't have root access. All the editing is for appuser crontab as appuser.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by "`vi`" you mean *actual* `vi` (not `vim`):

```
:set extended
:g/(CPU|Memory)_check/s/^/#/
```

This first enables extended regular expressions in search patterns with `set extended`, and then applies the substitution `s/^/#/` (inserts a `#`-character at the start of a line) to all lines that contains the string `CPU_check` or `Memory_check`.

In `vim`, you could use

```
:g/\(CPU\|Memory\)_check/s/^/#/
```

or

```
:g/\v(CPU|Memory)_check/s/^/#/
```

to do the same thing.

The `\v` escape in `vim` allows `vim` to use recognise the pattern as an extended regular expression. The `v` it `\v` is short for "very magic" (see `:help magic` in `vim`).

---

In `ed`, not supporting extended regular expressions, you could use the two separate editing commands

```
g/Memory_check/s/^/#/
g/CPU_check/s/^/#/
```

---

With a `sed` that supports extended regular expression via its `-E` option:

```
sed -E '/(CPU|Memory)_check/s/^/#/'
```

Or, with standard `sed`,

```
sed -e '/CPU_check/s/^/#/' -e '/Memory_check/s/^/#/'
```